# Change the orientation transition of the screen from right to left in Vertical Slider in Android

Tags: android, animation, slider

I am working with vertical slider Similar to Facebook in devices as shown in below image.  I am using library project **Facebook-like Slide-out Navigation** for the slider view.

My requirement is to show this Slider at both the ends of the screen, that is from left to right and from right to left as shown in Image.
My Requirement:

[image]

When I click on the LEFT TOP button, the screen oriented from left to right, which is correct.
**Problem is**: whenever the screen on the RIGHT TOP button the screen is oriented, directed from left to right but it should come from right to left.

I am working with Facebook-like Slide-out Navigation and below custom code:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);

        findViewById(R.id.sample_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                        SlideoutActivity.prepare(SampleActivity.this, R.id.inner_content, width);
                        startActivity(new Intent(SampleActivity.this,
                                MenuActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                });

        findViewById(R.id.sample_button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                SlideoutActivity.prepare(SampleActivity.this, R.id.inner_content, width);
                startActivity(new Intent(SampleActivity.this,
                        MenuOneActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_in_left);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_in_left);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. Hope this is what you are trying to implement.

The author is really nice, he provided a play store demo on his project page.

Comment: I think I have seen that.. in this demo also we have a single button on the top, left corner.. and having a single screen animation.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is an activity with two buttons/slidingmenus, one on the left and another on the right!

See https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java

Comment: In this demo, it is shown clear that my requirement is not full filled. What I need is, 2 sliders at both the side of the screen. Am i right ?

Comment: Have you checked the activity which says `Left and Right`. It provides two sliders at both sides.

The only difference that I have noted is that it doesn’t have a right action bar button to open the right drawer, you have to swipe it from right to left.

But I believe you can implement that with less trouble by checking the API doc for toggling `SlidingMenu#SecondaryMenu`

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions...!! In between I got another helpful Github link ... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

After a long research,  I am done with the task to have 2 sliders on both the end of the screen. Got valuable code from github link of [srikanthgr](https://github.com/srikanthgr/FacebookSlideOutmenu)

Thanks for the valuable code.